# How to parse the JSON in swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3, xcode8

I am trying to parse the JSON which i read from server response. I am able fetch the first level but after that i can traverse to the next level. As i am completely new to IOS, i explored and tried as much as i can but everything was in vein. I doubt am missing something in basic level.

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
```

print(json)

```
    {

"ab_report" = "[{\"label\":\"ART\",\"value\":187},{\"label\":\"SINDED\",\"value\":24},{\"label\":\"RES\",\"value\":1},{\"label\":\"REAL\",\"value\":1}]";

distslist =     (

            {

        "_id" =             {

            "$id" = 5732d884dbe782a63c760e3b;

        };

        "dt_code" = ADB;

        "dt_name" = Adilaasbad;

        "st_name" = 572d95c0dsdfbe7823348c981b3;

    },

            {

        "_id" =             {

            "$id" = 572d95d4dbsadfe7826b48c981b3;

        };

        "dt_code" = HEEWYD;

        "dt_name" = aassas;

        "st_name" = 572d95c0efghbe7823348dc981b3;

    }

)

"last_ssdate" = "Lase on : 2s0";

message = "";

"ressdfort" = "[{\"label\":\"Ded\",\"value\":71},{\"label\":\"Weed\",\"value\":0},{\"label\":\"Scrnitiated\",\"value\":0}]";

"scrort" = "[{\"label\":\"Physicals\",\"value\":8551},{\"label\":\"General\",\"value\":15752},{\"label\":\"Ees\",\"value\":2756}]";
```

}

print(json["ressdfort”]!)

```
[{"label":"Ded","value":71},{"label":"Weed","value":0},{"label":"Stiated","value":0}]
```

After this i want to take the values one by one with "label" and "value" from each object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: json["ressdfort”]! returns an `Array` with elements of type `Dictionary` '[Dictionary]`. Google how to deal with those types. If do stuff in Swift, you may want to read: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309

Comment: @shallowThought Thank you for your suggestion i gone through that link and got some basic ideas. when i print `print(type(of:json))` it is `__NSDictionaryI`  , `type(of:json["ressdfort"]!)` it is  `__NSCFString` and  `type(of:json["ressdfort"]!)` it is `Optional<Any`. I am trying to get as Array by `let sng  = json["ressdfort"] as! NSArray` but i got 'Could not cast value of type `__NSCFString' (0x10e819320) to 'NSArray' (0x10e819c58).` can you suggest me how can i take this further. Thanks!

Comment: Two thoughts: Prefer `Dictionary` ([String:Any] or something like that) to `NSDictionary` in Swift. Also, you JSON have JSON String embedded in it as JSON, so for `ressdfort`, `script ` and `ab_report` values, you have to call again `JSONSerialization`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now try this for getting "label" values.Pass your jsonObj to this function.Hope its working for you:)

```
 func parseJson(_ JsonDict: AnyObject)
    {

        if let dict = JsonDict["ressdfort"]  as? [AnyObject]{
            for dict1 in dict{
                if let textDist = (dict1 as? [String : AnyObject])?["label"]{
                    print("YOUR LABEL TEXT IS  \(String(describing: textDist))")

                }
            }

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alamofire and parse json response as follows:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, YOUR_URL, parameters: DIC_PARAMETERS, encoding: .URLEncodedInURL)
            .responseJSON { response in
                guard response.result.error == nil else {
                    print(response.result.error!)
                    return
                }

                if let value = response.result.value {
                    print("Your Response is: " + value.description)

                    if((response.result.value) != nil) {
                        let swiftyJsonVar = response.result.value!
                        do {
                            if let dicObj = swiftyJsonVar as? NSDictionary {
                               print("Response is dictionary")
                                print(dicObj)
                             let arrObj = dicObj["ab_report"] as NSArray
                             let arrObj2 = dicObj["distslist"] as NSArray
                // Then iterate your arrObj and do as per your requirment.

                            } else if let arrObj = swiftyJsonVar as? NSArray {
                                print("Response is an array")
                                print(arrObj)

                            } else {
                                print("response is not valid JSON data")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let bundle = json["ressdfort"] as! Array

for eachObject in bundle
{
    let label = (eachObject as! NSDictionary).valueForKey("label")! as! String
    let value =(eachObject as! NSDictionary).valueForKey("value")! as! String
    print(label) 
    print(value) 
}
```

Comment: I am sorry its not working, I am getting `Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'`